# jq need to re-arrange a list of objects to be a nested single object

Tags: json, ansible, jq

I have found myself needing to search through a few large large json responses via Ansible which has been quite slow. This appears to be related to the structure of the json response, so I need to convert it to a singular nested dictionary instead of the current list of dictionaries. Looking around, jmespath that comes with Ansible doesn't like to move a value to a key it seems. I have had some luck with a community plugin that adds jq support, but only if I hard code the top level dictionary.

with the following sample...

```
{
  "json": {
    "@code": "19",
    "@status": "success",
    "result": {
      "@count": "7003",
      "@total-count": "7003",
      "entry": [
        {
          "@location": "shared",
          "@name": "bgp_routers",
          "static": {
            "member": [
              "core-1",
              "core-2",
              "core-3",
              "supercore"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "@location": "shared",
          "@name": "web_servers",
          "description": "req-5",
          "static": {
            "member": [
              "web001",
              "web002",
              "web004"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "@location": "remote-site-1",
          "@name": "web_servers-2",
          "description": "req-100",
          "static": {
            "member": [
              "web001",
              "web003",
              "web004"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Id like to re-arrange it to look like this.

```
{
    "shared": {
      "bgp_routers": {
        "@location": "shared",
        "@name": "bgp_routers",
        "static": {
          "member": [
            "core-1",
            "core-2",
            "core-3",
            "supercore"
          ]
        }
      },
      "web_servers": {
        "@location": "shared",
        "@name": "web_servers",
        "description": "req-5",
        "static": {
          "member": [
            "web001",
            "web002",
            "web004"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
      "remote-site-1": {
      "web_servers-2": {
        "@location": "remote-site-1",
        "@name": "web_servers-2",
        "description": "req-100",
        "static": {
          "member": [
            "web001",
            "web003",
            "web004"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

So far, I can get to the object below but am unsure of how to merge the two "shared" keys
`.json.result.entry  | map({ (.["@location"]):  {( .["@name"] ): . }})`

Using add, it just seems to keep the last "shared" key.

```
[
  {
    "shared": {
      "bgp_routers": {
        "@location": "shared",
        "@name": "bgp_routers",
        "static": {
          "member": [
            "core-1",
            "core-2",
            "core-3",
            "supercore"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "shared": {
      "web_servers": {
        "@location": "shared",
        "@name": "web_servers",
        "description": "req-5",
        "static": {
          "member": [
            "web001",
            "web002",
            "web004"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "remote-site-1": {
      "web_servers-2": {
        "@location": "remote-site-1",
        "@name": "web_servers-2",
        "description": "req-100",
        "static": {
          "member": [
            "web001",
            "web003",
            "web004"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

As to why I'm not using the |combine filter in ansible, its really slow and resource intensive when larger loops are thrown at it. It removes and re-creates the dictionary on each iteration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `reduce`-based approach which iterates over the entries, and successively assigns each item to its intended path in the result object:

```bash
reduce .json.result.entry[] as $entry ({};
  .[$entry."@location"][$entry."@name"] = $entry
)
```

```json
{
  "shared": {
    "bgp_routers": {
      "@location": "shared",
      "@name": "bgp_routers",
      "static": {
        "member": [
          "core-1",
          "core-2",
          "core-3",
          "supercore"
        ]
      }
    },
    "web_servers": {
      "@location": "shared",
      "@name": "web_servers",
      "description": "req-5",
      "static": {
        "member": [
          "web001",
          "web002",
          "web004"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "remote-site-1": {
    "web_servers-2": {
      "@location": "remote-site-1",
      "@name": "web_servers-2",
      "description": "req-100",
      "static": {
        "member": [
          "web001",
          "web003",
          "web004"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hoYCHJY02UY)